# Replace date picker text feild with my own textfeild

Tags: javafx

I make a text field that accept a date and make a validation on it
I want to replace text feiled in date picker with
My own text feild any one can suggest to me what i should do?

Comment: Could you add more description as to what you want the new text box to do, that the original could not?

Comment: you don't need a custom textField, just use a TextFormatter on the existing editor

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DatePicker` component to enter a date. You can configure the `promptText` attribute of your component.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: the question is unclear .. but I think the OP already uses a DatePicker and wants validation on its editor .. just a guess, though :)